# Perfect set of zero measure is nowhere dense?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

is it true that a perfect set of measure zero is nowhere dense (here I am talking about a set $\Omega$ on an interval $[a,b]$)? The Cantor set would definitely confirm this statement, but I do not know if this is generally true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be the set in question. Since $E$ is closed, to show that $E$ is nowhere dense it's enough to show that $E$ has an empty interior.

But if $E$ has a non-empty interior then it contains an open interval $I$, and then $m(E)\geq m(I)>0$.

Answer (score 2):

If a closed set is dense in $(a, b)$, it contains $[a, b]$ (why?). And perfect sets are closed.

Now suppose $P$ is a perfect set. If it's not nowhere dense, it's dense on some interval $(a, b)$ - now what can we say about the measure of $P$?