# Are there doubly (left- and right-) perfect sets with Lebesgue measure zero?

Tags: reference-request, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

This question seems natural enough that the answer should be known, but I was unable to find a reference.

Call a subset $C$ of $\Bbb R$ left- (respectively, right-) perfect if it is perfect and if every point in $C$ is a limit point from the left (respectively, from the right). Are there any subsets of $\Bbb R$ that are Lebesgue-null, right-perfect *and* left-perfect?

Clearly, the standard Cantor set is neither right- nor left-perfect.

Comment: The second answer in this link may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2398468/perfect-set-of-zero-measure-is-nowhere-dense

Comment: It seems to me that the only left-perfect sets are $\emptyset$, $\mathbb{R}$, and $(-\infty, x]$.  The only sets that are right-perfect and left-perfect are thus $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @NateEldredge It may very well be, but right now I'm missing the way to prove it.

Comment: Let $y \in C^c$; I claim $[y, \infty) \subset C^c$.  For if not, then $x = \inf(C \cap (y, \infty))$ is in $C$ (because perfect sets are closed) and is not a limit point of $C$ from the left (because the interval $(y,x)$ contains no points of $C$).  Contradiction.  This means that $C^c$ is either empty or is of the form $(z, +\infty)$ for some $z \ge -\infty$.

Comment: @NateEldredge It's a shame that I didn't find this, but that's the game. You can post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only left-perfect sets are $\emptyset$, $\mathbb{R}$, and closed half-lines of the form $(-\infty, b]$.  So the only sets which are right-perfect and left-perfect are $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$, and the only set fitting the criteria of your question is $\emptyset$.

To see this, suppose $y \notin C$.  If there exists $x \in C$ with $x > y$, we can let $x_0 = \inf\{x \in C : x > y\}$.  Then $x_0 \in C$ since perfect sets are closed, but there are no points of $C$ between $y$ and $x_0$, so $x_0$ is not a limit point from the left, a contradiction.  Thus $[y, \infty) \subset C^c$.  It follows that $C^c$ is a half-line which is open since $C$ is closed, so $C^c = (b, \infty)$ for some $b$, or else $C^c = \mathbb{R}$ or $\emptyset$.